# Typescript infer value from subset of union for conditional type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm looking for a little help on type inference to narrow a union in TypeScript based on a conditional type.

Our API takes a set of parameters and validates them. As part of the validation process, it normalises all the values to make it easier for downstream processing. One of the parameters can be either an array of strings or an array of array of strings. When normalised that value is always converted to an array of array of strings.

To avoid having to write out each validated type explicitly (and maintain them) I am trying to infer the validated params from the incoming params (which have the same keys) with the resolved value. For example:

```
type IncomingParams = {
   names: string[] | Array<string[]> | undefined
   ages: string[] | undefined
}

// Post validation the object is the following
type Validated = {
   names: Array<string[]>
   ages: string[]

}
```

This is what I came up with but it *doesn't* ensure that when there is the union, it always resolves to an array of array.

```
type ArrayUnion<T> = T[] | T[][];

type Params = {
   names: ArrayUnion<string>
   ages: string[]
}

type ValidatedParams<P> = {
    [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends ArrayUnion<infer U>
        ? U[][]
        : NonNullable<P[K]>;
};

const validated: ValidatedParams<Params> = {} as any;

validated.names // This should be string[][]
validated.ages // This should be string[]
```

It may be that Typescript cannot differentiate the union, so one option I've explored is to use  `& { readonly _sym: unique symbol }` to uniquely identify `ArrayUnion`, although this approach hasn't worked either.

I'd appreciate any help in advance.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=2&module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAqgOwJYHs0B4AqAfFALxQAU+A2gLpQA+U1NtAlANwBQnokUACoiQBbAM6koAb05RZaRMIiiAXLATJ02PKOBwMaAOaEZsxAaWqdew7U4Bfbr2gA1RABsMAE0TAInwSKiuPzEZNKyslQA0lD6UADWECBYAGYCNKr80XQQAB6+aJ7i8EiomDi4+ikQcFAoxhGNUAD8dbS2TRGqAHI43QCubm6IAEZuEMHZhFx2XJwAxjg6UABu7l4+fqquHt6+-kIKQQFHoVJ2UIjiiGggc2u7m54AdPKK4lAA9J9MABYY4lEvywg08UBG0Cs+gM7RonAeG32zzMSlk3z+AKgQJBbjBEKxumhtk46IAwjh5nAID5YsIwG5FGhgD4tAslsAoGBDmJMtzxGETKZzCooFQAERYXFimgAGkFUDeFlFYoAVgolNL7NxFmhllzAgAmXmBCThCIokXiyWeaVyxqKy3itXvW3KlVYX5oaVwhwkn4AWSwngwKRA0KgTjUpU0FSIEmYDCYsKgAFpiJGShpyng42QE4xmLQoAAyKRQKmITw4NwgKAAfVEIGEqn6mAAjv1IU2RpKoLM-UwAMpQADuGCGWMg8xDGHm7hrsU8ECZIdrDqgwZS1SpTIXKTgWGEl2FMsuhUugP681+nJqKSwcCPwF+0B1weAWncUGvEHm8WeUAABJYCOEArDUUADhgwAAOTiGgWAcmAWCiKIGBjNAwBYN+Fa+BGL5QFgIwqr+wDiPoHIESkGBwHqwzzBA3BQEAA)

Comment: Using your code, if I assign `validated.names` to a variable (eg. `const test = validated.names`), it seems to have the expected `string[][]` type.

Comment: Hi @AlbertoRivera, thanks. I've put a playground together. strangely I get the error I've recorded about locally, but using the playground I get string[[] - however, the `ages` property is also string[][] when it should be string[]

Comment: @J-R based on the information you've provided in above comment, it leads me to believe that your workspace/project is using an older Typescript version where it couldn't correctly infer the type. try upgrading project/workspace to newer TS version to see if it remedies the problem. Also, it might be helpful to include your tsconfig.json when posting TS questions, as sometimes it can come down to configuration causing unexpected issues which don't show in playground.

Comment: `ages` is `string[][]` because it does extend `ArrayUnion`, since it's an array. Also, in your use case, if `names` pre-validation was `string[]`, should it be `string[][]` post-validation?

Comment: Hi @r3wt thanks for the suggestion, I've re-created it in a playground link above that has the config contained. I have updated my local typescript version and it now reflects the issue in the playground.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera in this case `names` is only meant to be a singlar array, for background we are performing operator logic based on the grouping of the arrays but only for some properties. I was hoping that Typescript may be able to infer based on the conditional type - i.e. if Union type then narrow, if not union don't narrow. By adding a unique symbol to the union type this can be done, however it's not possible to create the object without lots of hacking about. It may be that I'm looking for something that is and edge case and beyond the capabilities of the type system

Answer (score 1):

It seems there the `undefined` being added caused some issues. Here is a solution working in the TS playground

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=2&module=1#code/PTAEHUHsCcGsEsB2BzUBnSAbArgF3pIgFBG4CeADgKagCC00AhmQKqIGIA8AKgHygBeUAG1uoAD6huwgLoAaUADplACmkyJU2bICUGydkQATKgDMkVIyXLVQABUZMAtmkGgA3kVDfEjJ1TQALjoGZjYOTjRcaCRkXi9vRmQA4KiYlFk5BNBIXAALKmhg+iZWdkJI6Nj4gF9rShoANUZMeCNGXEsHZzROO34hT29vYQBpUCRQWCoySFN7GWC7MY0qAA9O41cSsPKuJFNC0BZ44bPQAH5QADlCa+xMTEYAI0wqThPtGWzz4NvEe6PF5vPorXgAbiINUhRAAxoQoqAAG4tNodSzBZqtdqdIzdPy9fEuAYeGqgRiuRiIMgwlHY9FGRS+fyuUAgKR5eCuNB5SAPIygZ40NKxL5EOlo3GKJIBbzs7ic7m8-mC4VVDLfIjsgDChFh0CoHQmTgomH8iFwHQ4cIRuFAFEcBKWjpcbiGwxlQREACIsEZvfIfsyUj6AFZ+AIBrJnXIFIqgQwmcyISxQkjwxCIh09ABMzp6bp+nuCwl9mH9gbOwa9wlL4ZZUbDkDyiG9Cm97SRVADleGscKJbrEbQjbrzdb7c73fkPopFcDdSAA